# Should we stop this kind of Ticker?

Tags: go, timer, cron, goroutine

I have a time ticker that will execute a function within time interval(eg every 5 minutes, 10 minutes). I create this time ticker within a goroutine. I heard that this kind of ticker could leak the memory even if the app stopped. This ticker will keep running as long as the app running. Should it stop? how to stop it properly? Here is my implementation:

```
go func() {
    for range time.Tick(5 * time.Minute) {
        ExecuteFunctionA()
    }
}()
```

What is the proper implementation for time ticker like this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a channel as a intermediary to stop the ticker properly.

Usually, I did it as the following:

```
var stopChan chan bool = make(chan bool)

func Stop() {
    stopChan <- true
}

func Run() {
    go func() {
       ticker := time.NewTicker(5 * time.Minute)
       for {
           select {
               case <- c.stopChan:
                   ticker.Stop()
                   return
               case <- ticker.C:
                   ExecuteFunctionA()
           } 
       }
    }()
}
```

And you can invoke `Stop` function at the time you want to stop the ticker safely.

Comment: consider using a context.

Comment: @mh-cbon what do you mean? Can you show some example code? Thanks a lot.

Comment: why not use defer ticker.Stop()?

Comment: please note the documentation for `ticker.Stop()`: you should drain the channel correctly as shown in the documentation: `if ticker.Stop() { <-ticker.C }`

Answer (score 2):

Nothing will leak if the 'app stopped'. The [warning in the documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Tick) refers to the fact that the garbage collector will not be able to reclaim the channel once it is created (`time.Tick()` initializes and returns a chan) and it will sit in memory even if you decide to `break` out of your `for` loop.
Based on your description in the question, this shouldn't be an issue for you since you want the ticker running as long as the app is running. But if you decide otherwise, you can use an alternative way like:

```
go func() {
  for {
    time.Sleep(time.Duration(5) * time.Minute)
    go ExecuteFunctionA()
    if someConditionIsMet {
      break // nothing leaks in this case
    }
  }
}()
```

Comment: time.Sleep is not equivalent to time.Ticker. If ExecuteFunctionA takes one minute to complete, one iteration takes six minutes with Sleep, and five minutes with a Ticker: https://golang.org/pkg/time/#NewTicker

Comment: Good catch. Sure you can run the `ExecuteFunctionA()` in a separate goroutine if the execution time is significant. I updated the code example.

Comment: IMHO, updated code couldn't resolve the problem proposed by @Peter. Consider that, if one iteration takes six minutes, there are two goroutines which will running the `ExecuteFunctionA`. There may be some concurrent problem which will put your program into a mess.

Comment: Just use [time.NewTicker](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#NewTicker) instead of time.Tick and call Stop when breaking the loop.